# Problem with \ref{} in Beamer

Tags: beamer, enumerate, hyperlink

In {article} environment, I have the following code:

```
\begin{enumerate}[\textit{Stage} $(1)$]
\item \label{st0} Something
    \item \label{st1} Something1
    \item \label{st2} Something2
\end{enumerate}
```

Through the paper, when I call

```
\ref{st1}
```

it immediately writes "Stage 2" with a hyperlink. However, I cannot reproduce it in beamer.
In particular, it only prints "1".

Do you have any clue on how to fix this?

Thanks in advance!!

**Edit**. Compilable Example.

```
\documentclass[english]{beamer}
\usepackage{lmodern}
\renewcommand{\sfdefault}{lmss}
\renewcommand{\ttdefault}{lmtt}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{amstext}
\hypersetup{
    colorlinks,
    citecolor=blue,
    linkcolor=blue
}
\usepackage{amsmath, amsthm, amssymb}
\newtheorem{prop}{Proposition}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[authoryear]{natbib}
\makeatletter
\newcommand\makebeamertitle{\frame{\maketitle}}
\AtBeginDocument{
  \let\origtableofcontents=\tableofcontents
  \def\tableofcontents{\@ifnextchar[{\origtableofcontents}{\gobbletableofcontents}}
  \def\gobbletableofcontents#1{\origtableofcontents}}
  \makeatletter
\renewcommand{\itemize}[1][]{%
    \beamer@ifempty{#1}{}{\def\beamer@defaultospec{#1}}%
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >2\relax\@toodeep\else
    \advance\@itemdepth\@ne
    \beamer@computepref\@itemdepth% sets \beameritemnestingprefix
    \usebeamerfont{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body}%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body begin}%
    \list
    {\usebeamertemplate{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}}
    {\def\makelabel##1{%
            {%
                \hss\llap{{%
                        \usebeamerfont*{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}%
                        \usebeamercolor[fg]{itemize \beameritemnestingprefix item}##1}}%
            }%
        }%
    }
    \fi%
    \setlength\itemsep{\fill}
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >1
     
    \fi%  
    \beamer@cramped%
    \raggedright%
    \beamer@firstlineitemizeunskip%
}
\def\enditemize{\ifhmode\unskip\fi\endlist%
    \usebeamertemplate{itemize/enumerate \beameritemnestingprefix body end}
    \ifnum \@itemdepth >1
    \vfil
    \fi%  
}
\makeatother
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\makeatother
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\setbeamercolor{math text}{fg=black!15!blue}
\setbeamertemplate{footline}[frame number]
\begin{document}
\title{Example
\today }
\begin{frame}{Stages}
\begin{center}
\begin{enumerate}[\textit{Stage} $(1)$]
\item \label{st0} Something happens.
\vspace{5mm}
    \item \label{st1} Something happens.
    \vspace{5mm}
    \item \label{st2} Something happens.
    \vspace{5mm}
    \item \label{st3} Something happens.
    \end{enumerate}\end{center}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}{Call the Stage}
    \begin{itemize}
        \item \ref{st1}
    \end{itemize}
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

**Edit 2**

See the attached article example.

```
 \documentclass[english,12pt]{article}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{newpxtext,newpxmath}
\usepackage{palatino}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{geometry}
 \geometry{
 a4paper,
 left=3.175cm,
 right=3.175cm,
 top=3.175cm,
 bottom=3.175cm,
 }
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{appendix}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{patterns,decorations.pathreplacing}
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.10}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[round]{natbib}
 \linespread{1.25}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\setcitestyle{square}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{tgpagella}
\hypersetup{
  colorlinks,
  citecolor=blue,
  linkcolor=blue,
  urlcolor=blue}
\makeatletter
\numberwithin{equation}{section}
\numberwithin{figure}{section}
\numberwithin{table}{section}
\interfootnotelinepenalty=10000
\usepackage{mdframed}
\mdfdefinestyle{myenvs}{%
  hidealllines=true,%
  nobreak=true, % comment this to allow breaking
  leftmargin=0pt,
  rightmargin=0pt,
  innerleftmargin=0pt,
  innerrightmargin=0pt,
}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myenvs]{prop}{Proposition}
\newtheorem{corollary}{Corollary}
\newmdtheoremenv[style=myenvs]{Lemma}{Lemma}
\usepackage{blindtext}
\usepackage{thmtools}
\usepackage{authblk}
\makeatother
\providecommand{\Propositionname}{Proposition}
\providecommand{\theoremname}{Theorem}

\begin{document}
\title{Example}
}
\author{me}
\date{\today}
\maketitle
\thispagestyle{empty}
\textbf{Keywords}
\newpage{}
\maketitle
\clearpage
\setcounter{page}{1}
\newpage
\section{Example}
\begin{enumerate}[\textit{Stage} $(1)$]
\item \label{st0} Something happens.
    \item \label{st1} Example.
\end{enumerate}
In \ref{st0}, something happens.
\end{document}
```

Comment: Can you make a compilable example? Are you using the `enumitem` package? That might not be the best idea in beamer...

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz I have provided an example. I hope it is clear now. Thanks for your comment

Comment: @Community I have now provided an example. In article, when I write \ref{st0} it writes  : "Stage 1" with a correct hyperlink that reminds to the corresponding label \label{st0}. I would like to reproduce the same in beamer. I hope it is clear now

Comment: I can not reproduce your claim that it works in article. By default enumerate has no optional argument, and with the enumerate package the \ref simply gives 2.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, @UlrikeFischer. See the attached edit 2. In my example, it works.

Comment: your example errors, but apart from this it uses enumitem (which is not really compatible with beamer as it breaks the overlay functions).

Comment: @UlrikeFischer Where do I use enumitem? Sorry about my probably stupid question

Comment: your example with article contains the line `\usepackage[shortlabels]{enumitem}`

Comment: Yes, I use it in article, I was wondering whether I can obtain the same result in Beamer @UlrikeFischer

Answer (score -1):

You may use `enumitem` package:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{enumitem}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}
\begin{enumerate}[label=\textit{Stage (\arabic*)}]
    \item \label{st0} Something
    \item \label{st1} Something1
    \item \label{st2} Something2
\end{enumerate}
\end{frame}
\begin{frame}
This is a reference to \ref{st1}.
\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Maybe my comment was ambiguous, I did not want to imply that one could use the enumitem package with beamer. That's not a good idea. It will make itemize bullets disappear and some other "funny" side effects. I was just wondering where the non-standard syntax of the first code fragment came from.

Comment: @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz Thanks a lot for your answer! Your code works if I open a new project, but unfortunately does not work if I use it in my example. What is the non-standard syntax in my code?

Comment: @Andrey L. Thanks a lot for your answer! Your code works if I open a new project, but unfortunately does not work if I use it in my example... Do you have any idea on why that happens?